# How to create API Key Token in Confluence?

Tags: python, confluence, confluence-rest-api

I get to a new project that required to integrate into Confluence.

So, I started with below script to trying to connect with Confluence.

```
from atlassian import Confluence

conf_site = 'https://confluence.fake-site.com/'
conf_user = 'farmer@fake.domain'
conf_pass = 'ZXCVBNMLKJHGFDSAQWERTYUIOP'

page_title = 'SAMPLE-TITLE' 
page_space = 'SAMPLE-SPACE'

# connect to Confluence 
conf = Confluence(url=conf_site, username=conf_user, password=conf_pass, verify_ssl=False)

status = conf.get_page_by_id('sample_ID')
print(status)
```

Return output belike HTML tag and some context with "wrong login" notice.
I found some answers that my problem is wrong about API Key Token and User's login password on Confluence login UI.

So, I tried to look in Confluence setting.

As attached image, I can't find the option to create an API Key Token.
[Profile Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pxJPu.png)
The other very 'similar' option is Personal Access Token but I'm not sure that was API Key Token.
[Personal Access Token](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGu1k.png)
I don't have any other clue to find out how to create API Key Token in Conflucence...

I did tried to search other answers on  Github
https://github.com/atlassian-api/atlassian-python-api/issues/332
Create API Key Token by Japanese website:
https://qiita.com/dyamaguc/items/bbd5ef1946ca79639b49

Comment: https://docs.searchunify.com/Content/Content-Sources/Atlassian-Jira-Confluence-Authentication-Create-API-Token.htm

Comment: @MoonMist  In my confluence setting, doesn't have tab named "Security"...

Comment: https://support.atlassian.com/atlassian-account/docs/manage-api-tokens-for-your-atlassian-account/ API tokens only work for conlfuence and jira cloud REST APIs. If you're just using the Python API, you should be able to just not use a token

Comment: @mrblue6 Thanks for your comment. But as above script, I didn't find out the reason I can't connect to Confluence. I'm now trying to connect through browser's cookie ( which have to import browser_cookie3).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to create a token. The token you have created is the Cloud Admin token that you can use to create new users such as below:

```
from atlassian import CloudAdminOrgs, CloudAdminUsers
apikey = 'xxxx'
cloud_admin_orgs = CloudAdminOrgs(admin_api_key=apikey)
```

However, to access pages you need a different token. You can get this token by navigating to: https://id.atlassian.com/manage-profile/security

From there you follow the instructions in the attached gif below

You can then access this using the `atlassian-python-api`

```
pip install atlassian-python-api
```

Sample code to access the pages:

```
from atlassian import Confluence

apikey = "xxxyyy"
server = 'https://company.atlassian.net/wiki/'
user = "you@company.com"

confluence = Confluence(
    url=server,
    username=user,
    password= apikey
    )

print(confluence.get_all_spaces())
```

[image: Instructions to create a token]